# React Deleting Item From Database

Tags: reactjs, axios, frontend, backend

I have my code where i list all items from database, and i put an icon next to every single item. When i click on that icon, i want item to be deleted. How can i do that?

That looks like this on the front part: [image]

I just started learning React and every help is appriciated, i would like to have `Axios.delete` in my `deleteButton()` function that deletes an item by its name.

I'm using react materials

my code:

```
export default function ItemControl() {
  const [itemList, setItemList] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    getItems();
  }, []);

  const url = "http://localhost:2000/appItem";

  const getItems = () => {
    // Sending HTTP GET request
    Axios.get(url).then((response) => {
      const itemListItems = [];
      response.data.forEach((resItem) => {
        itemListItems.push(resItem.name);
      });
      setItemList(itemListItems);
    });
  };

  const Demo = styled("div")(() => ({
    backgroundColor: "#f2f2f2",
  }));


  const deleteButton = (itemName) => {
    console.log(itemName);
    let newList = itemList.filter((el) => el.itemName !== itemName);
    setItemList(newList);
  };
  return (
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, maxWidth: 752 }}>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={12} md={12}>
          <Typography sx={{ mt: 4, mb: 2 }} variant="h6" component="div">
            Items
          </Typography>
          <Demo>
            <List>
              {itemList.map((li, index) => (
                <ListItem
                  secondaryAction={
                    <IconButton
                      edge="end"
                      aria-label="delete"
                      onClick={deleteButton}
                      id="name"
                    >
                      <DeleteIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                  }
                  key={li.itemId}
                >
                  <ListItemAvatar>
                    <Avatar>
                      <FolderIcon />
                    </Avatar>
                  </ListItemAvatar>
                  <ListItemText primary={li} />
                </ListItem>
              ))}
            </List>
          </Demo>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: You need to send an AJAX or query request to a server backend script that then runs the necessary MySQL for your db.  Have you started on a server backend script?

Comment: i have my backend. its mongodb and you can see i have axios.get from my backend already

Comment: Do you have a delete endpoint in your backend?

Comment: yes, it goes like "url/itemName"

Comment: The `axios.get` call is in your front-end.  What is the code for `appItem`?  That needs to do the deleting, and then return success/failure/whatever.  You already seem to be handling whatever response its giving in your `then()` call.  But that backend code would be useful to see.

Comment: Backand for deleting is '{url}/{itemName}'

Comment: Just call the backend delete function if you have one, what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is, i cannot tie the delete button to itemName. The one that's currently there is not working properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `deleteButton` event you did not call `axios.delete` to delete your record. Please do something like below:

```
const deleteButton = (itemName) => {
    console.log(itemName);
    axios.delete('url/itemName').then(() => {
        let newList = itemList.filter((el) => el.itemName !== itemName);

        setItemList(newList);
    });
};
```

**UPDATE**

```
return (
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, maxWidth: 752 }}>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={12} md={12}>
          <Typography sx={{ mt: 4, mb: 2 }} variant="h6" component="div">
            Items
          </Typography>
          <Demo>
            <List>
              {itemList.map((li, index) => (
                <ListItem
                  secondaryAction={
                    <IconButton
                      edge="end"
                      aria-label="delete"
                      onClick={() => deleteButton(li)}
                      id="name"
                    >
                      <DeleteIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                  }
                  key={li.itemId}
                >
                  <ListItemAvatar>
                    <Avatar>
                      <FolderIcon />
                    </Avatar>
                  </ListItemAvatar>
                  <ListItemText primary={li} />
                </ListItem>
              ))}
            </List>
          </Demo>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
  );
```

Comment: This way is not working because itemName goes undefined every time

Comment: because you did not pass itemName in delete function. I updated my answer with `onClick={() => deleteButton(li)}` please try it

Answer (score 0):

In order to know what item you want to delete, you have to pass it to your function `deleteButton`:

```
  <ListItem
    secondaryAction={
      <IconButton
        edge="end"
        aria-label="delete"
        onClick={() => deleteButton(li.itemName)} // this is changed
        id="name"
      >
        <DeleteIcon />
      </IconButton>
    }
    key={li.itemId}
  >
```